# React Native iPhone X SafeAreaView

Tags: ios, react-native, iphone-x

Does anyone know when the following component is being planned for release?
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Components/SafeAreaView

It currently isn't in the 0.49.X or 0.50 (pre) releases.

Alternatively can anyone recommend any other potential packages that can address the safe area zone issue for iPhone X in React Native?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the v0.50.0-rc.1 & v0.50.0-rc.0 releases.

A stable version will be released after the 1st of November.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/983b05441d3d23809b924de2e4bf96a55c47428d

[image]

Comment: what about Modals? does it keep Modal content within the safe ware as well?